# log4net WPF UserControl Appender won't update RichTextBox during the DoAppend event using a BackgroundWorker

Tags: log4net, backgroundworker

I'm wondering if anybody has ever run across this issue.  I'm trying to show all the logging events in a RichTextBox of a WPF application, and thought I could use the IAppender interface on the UserControl to tack on a global Appender.

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to run a "long running" process in the background and create logger.Info("text") events during the DoWork event.

The issue I'm having is that the DoAppend event fires, and it appears that the text gets updated during the Dispatcher event, but the UI does not reflect this.

Here is my LogAppender class:

```
public partial class LogAppender : UserControl, IAppender
{
    public LogAppender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
    }

    public log4net.Layout.PatternLayout Layout
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        this.LogTextBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(
                delegate
                {
                    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

                    this.Layout.Format(writer, loggingEvent);

                    this.LogTextBlock.AppendText(writer.ToString());
                }));
    }
}

<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="LogTextBlock"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml button click and backgroundworker code:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    protected static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Complete");
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        logger.Info("End");
    }
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Height="30" Click="Button_Click_1">Start</Button>
    <local:LogAppender Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

I've tried just binding a TextBlock to the text being generated by the DoAppend method as well as just setting the Text property of a TextBlock, to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing some small but huge point, but I scratched my head for about 3 hours this afternoon to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks
Bryan

Answer (score 1):

The log4net Appender [here](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/logging-display-and-wpf/) might help you.  In essence, Pete has implemented a lognet Appender that supports INotifyPropertyChanged and exposes a property that is the concatenation of all of the messages logged so far.  The sample program that is available via a link from the page that I linked above shows how to make your view bind to the output of the Appender.  I have not actually used it, so I can't comment on how useful (or not) it is, but it does seem to be trying to solve the same problem that you are trying to solve.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I actually did see this post and used it as a starting point.  The problem I'm thinking with the original post here is that the backgroundworker would not let me update the UI thread (even though I was dispatching everything correctly).  My second post uses the BackgroundWorkers UpdateProgress event which allows us to update the UI easier.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a quick solution to this particular problem.  What I did do to solve my problem of getting log4net logs into a WPF form was create a bit of a hack (or maybe not??).

I created a singleton that exposes the log4net "Log" text one line at a time (didn't want to use up much memory).  Basically, the SingletonAppender has one property on it, "Log", that gets changed or updated during the DoAppend event of the custom IAppender shown below.

```
public class SingletonAppender
{
    private static volatile SingletonAppender instance;

    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private string log = string.Empty;

    private SingletonAppender() 
    {

    }

    public static SingletonAppender Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new SingletonAppender();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public string Log
    {
        get
        {
            string retValue = this.log;

            // whenever we "get" the Log property, reset the underlying value to empty
            this.log = string.Empty;

            return retValue;
        }

        set
        {
            this.log = value;
        }
    }
}

public class LogAppender : IAppender
{
    private string name = string.Empty;

    public LogAppender()
    {
    }

    #region IAppender Members

    public void Close()
    {
    }

    public void DoAppend(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        string retValue = string.Empty;

        if (this.Layout != null)
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            this.Layout.Format(writer, loggingEvent);
            retValue = writer.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            retValue = loggingEvent.MessageObject.ToString();
        }

        SingletonAppender.Instance.Log += retValue;
    }

    public log4net.Layout.PatternLayout Layout
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I create a "heart beat" Timer in the backgroundworker to get the log events that are happening during the process:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    protected static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         this.LogTextBox.AppendText(SingletonAppender.Instance.Log);
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Complete");
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Start");
        Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerCallback), sender, 500, 2000);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        logger.Info("End");
    }

    public void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (state != null)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = state as BackgroundWorker;

            if (worker != null && worker.IsBusy)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(0, null);
            }
        }
    }
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Height="30" Click="Button_Click_1">Start</Button>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="LogTextBox"/>
</Grid>
```